# General question about von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am just introduced to the topic of von Neumann algebras in a second-year graduate course on operator algebras. It is defined as a strongly-closed $^*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$, but I read that it could as well been defined as weakly-closed, and others. The problem is that I have $0$ feeling with these different topologies. I know some defintions (SOT is the locally convex topology generated by the point-separating family of seminorms $\{p_x : H → \mathbb{C}, u ↦ \lVert u(x) \rVert \mid x ∈ H \}$). I just really don't know what this *means*. That is, what I should think of when I read these sentences. I know this is a very vague question (probably requiring a long answer), but any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A correction: von Neumann algebras cannot be defined as the norm-closed subalgebras of $B(H)$ (even though they are norm closed). I don't know if there is any way to answer your question beyond "work with it and you'll gain understanding over time", but this wiki page has a diagram relating the different topologies that might help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_topologies#List_of_topologies_on_B(H)

Comment: That is helpful, thanks! (Corrected my post btw.) The problem with time is, that my exam is in 5 days... :p

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman Good luck then :P